# Determines if the array list is sorted

Tags: java, sorting, output

I need to estimate if the array list is sorted (don't sort).

When Strings are sorted, they are in alphabetical order.
I try to use [compareTo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29) method to determine which string comes first

And return true if the array list is sorted, else false.

**Code:**

```
public boolean isSorted()
{
    boolean sorted = true;        
    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i-1).compareTo(list.get(i)) != 1) sorted = false;
    }

    return sorted;
}
```

**Easy test:**

```
    ArrayList<String> animals = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayListMethods zoo = new ArrayListMethods(animals); 
    animals.add("ape");
    animals.add("dog");
    animals.add("zebra");

    //test isSorted
    System.out.println(zoo.isSorted());
    System.out.println("Expected: true");

    animals.add("cat");
    System.out.println(zoo.isSorted());
    System.out.println("Expected: false");

    animals.remove("cat");
    animals.add(0,"cat");
    System.out.println(zoo.isSorted());
    System.out.println("Expected: false");

    **Output:**
    false
    Expected: true
    false
    Expected: false
    false
    Expected: false
```

This easy test shows only `1/3` coverage.

How to solve this issue.

Comment: how can you determine if the list is sorted by simply checking just 2 elements? what if those 2 elements were in sort but others are not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a small bug in your method. Should be :

```
public boolean isSorted()
{
    boolean sorted = true;        
    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i-1).compareTo(list.get(i)) > 0) sorted = false;
    }

    return sorted;
}
```

`>0` instead of `!=1`, you can't be sure that `1` is returned..

Comment: you don't need `sorted` variable at all. Return false immediately when `if` check fails.

Answer (score 2):

Change the condition :

```
if (list.get(i - 1).compareTo(list.get(i)) >0)
```

You should check for `>0` instead of `!=-1` .

Go through the documentation of [compareTo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29)

> the value 0 if the argument string is equal to this string; a value less than 0 if this string is lexicographically less than the string argument; and **a value greater than 0 if this string is lexicographically greater than the string argument.**

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Sort {
public static void main(String []args) {
    List<String> l1=new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> l2=new ArrayList<String>();
    l1.add("a");
    l1.add("b");
    l1.add("c");

    l2.add("b");
    l2.add("c");
    l2.add("a");

     if(isSorted(l1)){
         System.out.println("already sorted");
     }
    else{
         Collections.sort(l1);
     }
   }
public static boolean isSorted(List<String> list){
    String previous = "";
    for (String current: list) {
        if (current.compareTo(previous) < 0)
            return false;
        previous = current;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a utily method like `isSortedList(List list)`.

```
public static boolean isSortedList(List<? extends Comparable> list)
{
    if(list == null || list.isEmpty())
        return false;

    if(list.size() == 1)  
        return true;

    for(int i=1; i<list.size();i++)
    {
        if(list.get(i).compareTo(list.get(i-1)) < 0 )
            return false;
    }

    return true;    
}
```

As as utility method, you can use it anywhere.

Comment: in for loop statment there is syntax error so edit it

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the  compareTo expresion to any positive number, which indicates that the previous element is alphabetically after the current element, hence the list is not ordered

```
    public boolean isSorted()
    {
        boolean sorted = true;        
        for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i-1).compareTo(list.get(i)) > 0) sorted = false;
        }

        return sorted;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for unsorted case.

This means that if you are assuming sorting ascending, the unsorted case will be finding an element at index `i` being out of order from index `i-1`
where `element[i] < element[i-1]`.